# Http get request responseType error: Angular 4

Tags: angular

I am making an http GET call in my app which is constructed in the following way:

```
this.authHttp.get(serviceUrl, { responseType: ResponseContentType.Blob }).toPromise()
    .then((res) => {
............................
```

But, I'm getting an error in my IDE saying: (screenshot attached)

[image]

If I change the call to a POST call (which it is not), the error goes away. Can somebody point out the mistake I'm making here? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

ResponseContentType is from the old http module. If you're using the newer HttpClient, use `responseType: 'blob'`

Answer (score 0):

Angular 2
You need to import and  instantiate the Headers and RequestOptios classes :

```
import { Http, Headers, RequestOptions } from '@angular/http';
```

and use it in the method

```
const headers:Headers = new Headers();
headers.append('responseType', ResponseContentType.Blob);
const opts: RequestOptions = new RequestOptions({ headers  });
this.authHttp.get('url', opts).toPromise()
   .then((res) => {
    ............................;
```

Angular > 4

```
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
```

Use it

```
const httpHeaders: HttpHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
httpHeaders.append('responseType', ResponseContentType.Blob);
this.authHttp.get('url', { headers: httpHeaders }).toPromise()
       .then((res) => {
        ............................;
```